# Draw a circle in the middle of canvas

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

Having  -

**HTML -**

```
<canvas  id="myCanvas" >
        </canvas>

        <script>

              var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
              var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
              var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
              var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
              var radius = 30;

              context.beginPath();
              context.arc(centerX,centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
              context.fillStyle = 'blue';
              context.fill();



        </script>
```

**CSS-**

```
#myCanvas {
    border:2px solid;
    display:inline-block;
    width:500px;
    height:400px;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/urielz/3E656/

but I get not accurate circle  .  How can I make it accurate circle  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set explicitly the size of your canvas, otherwise it will get the default size: 300x150.

you should do something like this

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="400"></canvas>
```

or via javascript (before getting the context)

```
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 400;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

Comment: I want it to be according to the #myCanvas size's

Answer (score 6):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3E656/2/)

If you just want set the canvas size in CSS, change your code to:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(canvas);
    if (canvas.getContext) {
        canvas.width = parseInt(style.getPropertyValue('width'));
        canvas.height = parseInt(style.getPropertyValue('height'));
    }

    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
    var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
    var radius = 30;

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fillStyle = 'blue';
    context.fill();
    context.lineWidth = 5;
    context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
    context.stroke();

    this.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    this.fill();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the width of your canvas, like so:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="400"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place below code after begin path:

```
    var centerX = canvas.width;
    var centerY = canvas.height;
context.arc(centerX*0.5,centerY*0.5,10,0 ,radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
```

Css:

```
#myCanvas {
    border:2px solid;
    display:inline-block;
    width:600px;
    height:300px;

}
```